# Need multiple subqueries that return all records in each separately

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I need to build a report that will show me each employee (main query), and the date and/or results of each test, with a separate column(s) for each test. I would like the results of my query to look like this:

```
FName LName     TB Date     TB Result    XrayDate  
--------------------------------------------------

Bob   Jones     10/1/2016   P           10/1/2016  
                9/1/2015    P           8/1/2015  
                9/15/2014   N           7/1/2014  
                8/3/2013    N   
                10/1/2012   Q   
                9/4/2011    P   
                8/16/2010   P
```

Below is the SQL I have now, with subqueries in my FROM statement, to pull in the TB Date/Result, and the XRayDate, but the results multiply once I add the 2nd subquery for XRayDate, giving me 21 results instead of a total of 7 rows of data.

```
EMPLOYEE.FLDLNAME, 
EMPLOYEE.FLDFNAME,
EMPLOYEE.FLDREC_NUM,
TUBER.FLDDATE as "TUBER Date",
TUBER.FLDCLASS as "TUBER Result",
XRayDate.FLDDATE as "XRay Date"
FROM   EMPLOYEE EMPLOYEE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT TUBER.FLDDATE, TUBER.FLDCLASS, TUBER.FLDEMPLOYEE
FROM   TUBER TUBER) TUBER
ON  EMPLOYEE.FLDREC_NUM = TUBER.FLDEMPLOYEE
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT PHYSLOG.FLDDATE, PHYSLOG.FLDTYPE,PHYSLOG.FLDEMPLOYEE
FROM   PHYSLOG PHYSLOG 
WHERE PHYSLOG.FLDTYPE = 'CXR') XrayDate
ON EMPLOYEE.FLDREC_NUM = XrayDate.FLDEMPLOYEE  `EMPLOYEE.FLDLNAME
```

Here is a sample of the result using the SQL Above:

```
Fname LName TB Date     TB Result   Xray Date
---------------------------------------

Bob   Jones 10/1/2016   P          10/1/2016  
            10/1/2016   P          8/1/2015  
            10/1/2016   P          7/1/2014  
            9/1/2015    P          10/1/2016  
            9/1/2015    P          8/1/2015  
            9/1/2015    P          7/1/2014  
            9/15/2015   N          10/1/2016  
            9/15/2015   N          8/1/2015  
            9/15/2015   N          7/1/2014  
            8/3/2013    N          10/1/2016  
            8/3/2013    N          8/1/2015  
            8/3/2013    N          7/1/2014  
            10/1/2012   Q          10/1/2016  
            10/1/2012   Q          8/1/2015  
            10/1/2012   Q          7/1/2014  
            9/4/2011    P          10/1/2016   
            9/4/2011    P          8/1/2015  
            9/4/2011    P          7/1/2014  
            8/16/2010   P          10/1/2016  
            8/16/2010   P          8/1/2015  
            8/16/2010   P          7/1/2014
```

I am newer to subqueries in SQL Developer, so your suggestions/feedback are welcome.

Comment: try group by in your second sub query .  SELECT max(PHYSLOG.FLDDATE)FLDDATE , PHYSLOG.FLDTYPE,PHYSLOG.FLDEMPLOYEE
      FROM   PHYSLOG PHYSLOG 
      WHERE PHYSLOG.FLDTYPE = 'CXR'
   group by PHYSLOG.FLDTYPE,PHYSLOG.FLDEMPLOYEE

Comment: If the suggestion above doesn't help try take a peek at [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query).  It explains how helpful sample data can be, when trying to answer a question.

Comment: The concept of an alias is to provide a different name to an object. This is usually done to type less. Aliasing your tables with the same name as the table is just an exercise in extra typing. It is really the opposite of providing clarity. You have to look at it twice to realize what it is doing. And in your subqueries don't select columns you are not using (you don't have to select the column to be able to use it in a join).

Answer (score 0):

Row_number tests and full join by rn.  Cross/outer apply the result, like that

```
SELECT
    EMPLOYEE.FLDLNAME, 
    EMPLOYEE.FLDFNAME,
    EMPLOYEE.FLDREC_NUM,
    TUBER_FLDDATE as "TUBER Date",
    TUBER_FLDCLASS as "TUBER Result",
    XRayDate_FLDDATE as "XRay Date"
FROM   EMPLOYEE EMPLOYEE 
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TUBER_FLDDATE = TUBER.FLDDATE,
            TUBER_FLDCLASS = TUBER.FLDCLASS,
            XrayDate_FLDDATE = XrayDate.FLDDATE 
      FROM (SELECT rn = row_number() over(order by TUBER.FLDDATE), TUBER.FLDDATE,    TUBER.FLDCLASS
           FROM TUBER 
           WHERE EMPLOYEE.FLDREC_NUM = TUBER.FLDEMPLOYEE) TUBER
      FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT rn = row_number() over(order by PHYSLOG.FLDDATE), PHYSLOG.FLDDATE
           FROM  PHYSLOG  
           WHERE PHYSLOG.FLDTYPE = 'CXR' AND EMPLOYEE.FLDREC_NUM = PHYSLOG.FLDEMPLOYEE) XrayDate 
              ON XrayDate.rn=TUBER.rn
    ) tests
```

Comment: This is brilliant! And returns exactly as I needed! Thank you!

Comment: One additional question. I have to add about 8 more subqueries to this, all having the WHERE EMPLOYEE.FLDREC_NUM = (table).FLDEMPLOYEE relationship. New one will use same table as XRayDate, but Type = TBQEST and will need Max Date vs all dates. Can you explain, once I create another Full Outer Join, what should the "ON" clause look like? (e.g. New subquery alias will be TBQESTDate. Will this be TBQESTDate.rn=?.rn or something else)? Thanks

Comment: You need to FULL JOIN the third table ON `coalesce(XrayDate.rn, TUBER.rn) = TBQESTDate.rn`. And so on, for n subquries of the kind use coalesce(<subq_1>.rn,..<subq_n-1>.rn) = <subq_n>.rn

Comment: Thank you, this worked successfully, but when I add the 4th subquery, identical by design to the 3rd, but changed the coalesce formula to ON COALESCE( XrayDate.rn, TUBER.rn, TBQESTDate.rn) = TITER.rn (new subquery alias is TITER), but that returns error: Incorrect syntax near '='. I'm guessing this is related to the coalesce formula?

Comment: `ON COALESCE( XrayDate.rn, TUBER.rn, TBQESTDate.rn) = TITER.rn` looks good provided all aliases and columns are properly defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your query significantly by:

- Not aliasing tables with the same name they already have (as mentioned by [Sean Lange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813116/sean-lange) in the comments above). For example there's no point in stating `FROM EMPLOYEE EMPLOYEE` as you can already refer to the `EMPLOYEE` table with the identifier `EMPLOYEE`. Instead try using shorthand identifiers to make the query quicker to write and easier to read.
- Not using subqueries in your `JOIN`s unless you really need to

So for example:

```
SELECT  e.FLDLNAME, 
        e.FLDFNAME,
        e.FLDREC_NUM,
        t.FLDDATE AS [TUBER Date],
        t.FLDCLASS AS [TUBER Result],
        x.FLDDATE AS [XRay Date]
FROM EMPLOYEE e
LEFT OUTER JOIN TUBER t ON e.FLDREC_NUM = t.FLDEMPLOYEE
LEFT OUTER JOIN PHYSLOG x ON e.FLDREC_NUM = x.FLDEMPLOYEE
WHERE x.FLDTYPE = 'CXR'
```

should give you the same results as the query in your question.

Now, if you get a greater number of records returned when the `JOIN`s are included than you do without them, this indicates that there are either:

- Multiple records in the `TUBER` table for each value of `FLDEMPLOYEE`
- Multiple records in the `PHYSLOG` table for each value of `FLDEMPLOYEE`
- or both!

You can check for this by returning a bit more detail from these tables:

```
SELECT  e.FLDLNAME, 
        e.FLDFNAME,
        e.FLDREC_NUM,
        t.*,
        x.*
FROM EMPLOYEE e
LEFT OUTER JOIN TUBER t ON e.FLDREC_NUM = t.FLDEMPLOYEE
LEFT OUTER JOIN PHYSLOG x ON e.FLDREC_NUM = x.FLDEMPLOYEE
WHERE x.FLDTYPE = 'CXR'
```

I'd recommend picking some relevant fields instead of actually using `t.*` and `x.*`, but I don't know your table structure as you haven't provided it.

If you figure out that there are multiple records in one of your `JOIN`ed tables for each value of `FLDEMPLOYEE`, you'll need to decide how you want to handle this, most likely either by doing some further filtering of the data in the `WHERE` clause, or by using a `GROUP BY` clause.

For example, if you realise that there are multiple records in the `TUBER` table for each value of `FLDEMPLOYEE`, you might see that you can filter down to just the records you are interested in using some other field in the `TUBER` table:

```
SELECT  e.FLDLNAME, 
        e.FLDFNAME,
        e.FLDREC_NUM,
        t.FLDDATE AS [TUBER Date],
        t.FLDCLASS AS [TUBER Result],
        x.FLDDATE AS [XRay Date]
FROM EMPLOYEE e
LEFT OUTER JOIN TUBER t ON e.FLDREC_NUM = t.FLDEMPLOYEE
LEFT OUTER JOIN PHYSLOG x ON e.FLDREC_NUM = x.FLDEMPLOYEE
WHERE x.FLDTYPE = 'CXR'
AND t.OtherField = 'SomeValue'
```

As long as you're certain that whatever additional filtering you apply will only return one record from the `TUBER` table per `FLDEMPLOYEE` value (and always will), this should work fine.

Alternatively, if for example you realise that there are multiple records in the `PHYSLOG` table for each value of `FLDEMPLOYEE`, you may want to only return the record with the most recent date in the `FLDDATE` field:

```
SELECT  e.FLDLNAME, 
        e.FLDFNAME,
        e.FLDREC_NUM,
        t.FLDDATE AS [TUBER Date],
        t.FLDCLASS AS [TUBER Result],
        MAX(x.FLDDATE) AS [Most Recent XRay Date]
FROM EMPLOYEE e
LEFT OUTER JOIN TUBER t ON e.FLDREC_NUM = t.FLDEMPLOYEE
LEFT OUTER JOIN PHYSLOG x ON e.FLDREC_NUM = x.FLDEMPLOYEE
WHERE x.FLDTYPE = 'CXR'
GROUP BY e.FLDLNAME, 
         e.FLDFNAME,
         e.FLDREC_NUM,
         t.FLDDATE,
         t.FLDCLASS
```